# Sorting not working in the Gridview as Required

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I tried the sorting functionality like below

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdUser"
                AllowPaging="true"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                OnDataBound="grdUser_DataBound"
                OnRowDeleting="grdUser_RowDeleting"
                OnPreRender="PreRenderGrid"
                runat="server"
                Width="100%"
                border="1"
                DataKeyNames="Id"
                PageSize="10"
                EmptyDataText="No Records Found"
                OnPageIndexChanging="grdUser_PageIndexChanging"
                EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false"
                CssClass="hoverTable"
                AllowSorting="true"
                OnSorting="grdUser_Sorting"
                ShowFooter="false"
                HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td"
                OnRowCommand="grdUser_RowCommand">
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="k-alt" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width="5">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="Username" SortExpression="username" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email ID" SortExpression="email" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ngoname" HeaderText="NGO Name"  ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="usertype" HeaderText="UserType" ItemStyle-Width="30" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserRoleName" HeaderText="User Role" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="active" HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="active" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" AlternateText="Edit" ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" CommandName="eEdit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CausesValidation="false" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" AlternateText="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
```

Also see my code behind:-

```
protected void grdUser_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = Session["tbl_User"] as DataTable;
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dt);
        dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
        grdUser.DataSource = dataView;
        grdUser.DataBind();
    }

    private string GetSortDirection(string column)
    {   
        string sortDirection = "ASC";
        string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;
        if (sortExpression != null)
        {
            if (sortExpression == column)
            {
                string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
                if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "ASC"))
                {
                    sortDirection = "DESC";
                }
            }
        }
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;
        return sortDirection;
    }
```

But when I debugged the code, I am always getting dt as null. 
Please help

**UPDATE**

Code for binding gridview:-

```
protected void BindGrid()
    {
        string username = string.Empty;
        string usertype = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT usertype,username  FROM tbl_User WHERE username=@username", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Session["User"].ToString();

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    username = dr["username"].ToString();
                    usertype = dr["usertype"].ToString();
                }
            }
            conn.Close();

            string query = string.Empty;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(usertype))
            {
                if (usertype == "0") // superadmin
                {
                    query = "select tbl_User.Id,tbl_ngoname.ngo_name, tbl_User.username,tbl_User.email,tbl_User.usertype,tbl_User.active,(CASE WHEN tbl_User.usertype='1' THEN 'Admin' WHEN tbl_User.usertype='0' THEN 'Super Admin' WHEN tbl_User.usertype='2' THEN 'User' END) AS UserRoleName FROM tbl_User INNER JOIN tbl_ngoname on tbl_ngoname.Id = tbl_User.NgoId ORDER By Id DESC";
                }
                if (usertype == "1") // admin
                {
                    query = "select tbl_User.Id,tbl_ngoname.ngo_name, tbl_User.username,tbl_User.email,tbl_User.usertype,tbl_User.active,(CASE WHEN usertype='1' THEN 'Admin' WHEN usertype='0' THEN 'Super Admin' WHEN usertype='2' THEN 'User' END) AS UserRoleName from tbl_User INNER JOIN tbl_ngoname on tbl_ngoname.Id = tbl_User.NgoId WHERE usertype != '0' ORDER By Id DESC";
                }
                if (usertype == "2") // user
                {
                    query = "select tbl_User.Id,tbl_ngoname.ngo_name, tbl_User.username,tbl_User.email,tbl_User.usertype,tbl_User.active,(CASE WHEN usertype='1' THEN 'Admin' WHEN usertype='0' THEN 'Super Admin' WHEN usertype='2' THEN 'User' END) AS UserRoleName from tbl_User INNER JOIN tbl_ngoname on tbl_ngoname.Id = tbl_User.NgoId WHERE username='" + username + "' ORDER By Id DESC";
                }

                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                grdUser.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                grdUser.DataBind();
                DisablePageDirections();
                grdUser.BottomPagerRow.Visible = true;
                Session["tbl_User"] = ds.Tables[0];
            }
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

ADDED MORE CODE:-

```
private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are setting session with name tbl_user and getting with name GridViewData. Is this alright ?

Comment: Am I doing something wrong here, coz i took from the net and used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting session with name `tbl_user` on page load and when you get it you are getting with `GridViewData`.

On page load you set session with name tbl_user

```
Session["tbl_User"] = dt;
```

And you get it with name GridViewData

```
DataTable dt = Session["GridViewData"] as DataTable;
```

When you get the datatable from session in grdUser_Sorting change it like this

```
 protected void grdUser_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    //Retrieve the table from the session object.
    DataTable dt = Session["tbl_user"] as DataTable;
    if (dt != null)
    {
        //Sort the data.
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
        grdUser.DataSource = Session["tbl_user"];
        grdUser.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried, but getting error as `Cannot find column username.`

Comment: Post the code from which you fill the datatable from DB.

Comment: Where is your dt which you have used in page_load.I can't see it in the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75677/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-nadeem).

Comment: Yes, In prerender grid it was taking the default gridview binding that is why it was not able to update and show. I corrected that and it worked for me. Actually i got help from yous solution only.